# React Native : Warning:Stateless function components cannot be given refs after adding ref to TextInput

Tags: react-native

After adding ref to TextInput, I got a warning "Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail" and I cannot focus the TextInput.Why it is not working.

```
    export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         username: '',
         password: '',
         };
       render() {
        return(
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
         <ScrollView ref="scrollView" style={[styles.container]}>
         <View style={styles.inputField}>
          <Image
            source={require('../images/username.png')}
            style={[styles.icon]}
          />
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Username"
            returnKeyType="next"
            placeholderTextColor="grey"
            onSubmitEditing={(event)=>this.textInput.focus()}
            onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username 
            })}
            blurOnSubmit={false}
            value={this.state.username}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputField}>
          <Image
            source={require('../images/password.png')}
            style={[styles.icon]}
          />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="grey"
          underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
          onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
          ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
          returnKeyType="done"
          value={this.state.password}
          secureTextEntry={true}
          blurOnSubmit={true}
          />                  
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
   )
  }
```

**Updated**: I updated the code for better understanding.

Comment: does your component have a state `this.state = {}` because stateless components do not use states and you are trying to use `setstate`

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen.Yes,setState is working. But the warning is there

Comment: can u show your component create method does it `extend Component` or is it just a class

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen The component is written in the format of  `class LoginScreen extends Component{}`

Comment: like the answer says below do you have a `contructor` added

Comment: Yes I have @NaveedSheriffdeen

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}` and `onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}` you cannot use a state-less component. You can use a PureComponent or Component.I think you should use PureComponent. Also you have to add a constructor for initialize your state. Try this:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';

class YourComponentName extends PureComponent {
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.state={
      username:'',
      password:''
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      //Your render function code
      .
      .
      .
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Username"
      returnKeyType="next"
      placeholderTextColor="grey"
      onSubmitEditing={(event)=>this.textInput.focus()}
      onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({ username })}
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      value={this.state.username}
    />
      .
      .
      .

    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder="Password"
      placeholderTextColor="grey"
      underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
      onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({ password })}
      ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
      returnKeyType="done"
      value={this.state.password}
      secureTextEntry={true}
      blurOnSubmit={true}
    />

  );
  }
}
```

Comment: No luck.I changed `Component` to `PureComponent` .Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I´m sorry for the delay. You can do this without using refs. Try to use this approach using state component:

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: '',
      password: '',
      focusPasswordInput: false,
    };
  }

  handleUsernameInputSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      focusPasswordInput:true
    });
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ScrollView ref="scrollView" style={[styles.container]}>
          <View style={styles.inputField}>
            <Image
              source={require('../images/username.png')}
              style={[styles.icon]}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="Username"
              returnKeyType="next"
              placeholderTextColor="grey"
              onSubmitEditing={() => this.handleUsernameInputSubmit()}
              onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({
                username
              })}
              blurOnSubmit={false}
              value={this.state.username}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.inputField}>
            <Image
              source={require('../images/password.png')}
              style={[styles.icon]}
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="Password"
              placeholderTextColor="grey"
              underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
              onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
              focus={this.state.focusPasswordInput}
              returnKeyType="done"
              value={this.state.password}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              blurOnSubmit={true}
            />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```